# How to import "RECYCLER" folders into Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, import, recycle-bin, forensics

question:
**If I connect a HDD to my PC, how can I import the `RECYCLER` folder into Windows XP?**
In other words: **How can I tell Windows XP to include the content of `D:\RECYCLER\` in the recycle bin?**

case in point:
I have 2 HDDs in my PC. Both contain `RECYCLER` folders in the root dir.
The files in `C:\RECYCLER\` are displayed in the WIN XP recycle bin.
The files in `D:\RECYCLER\` however don't show up there. The cause is probably that the `D:` drive was previously used in another WIN XP PC and the deletions took place there.
So how can I integrate `D:\RECYCLER\` so that its files show up in the recycle bin?

Answer (score 1):

Per chance, I just discovered a workaround:

1. backup the content of `D:\RECYCLER\` to avoid dataloss
2. create an empty file in `D:\`
3. delete this file – this creates the directory `D:\RECYCLER\%SID_new%\` where `%SID_new%` is the [SID of the user that performed the deletion](http://dereknewton.com/2010/06/recycle-bin-forensics-in-windows-7-and-vista/).
4. delete `D:\RECYCLER\%SID_new%\`
5. rename `D:\RECYCLER\%SID_old%\` to `D:\RECYCLER\%SID_new%\`
6. Maybe (I'm not sure) this last step is optional. The deleted files in the `RECYCLER` folder are named `D%drive_letter%%index_number%.%file_extension%` where `%drive_letter%` is the drive letter of the original file location, `%index_number%` is a counter, and `%file_extension%` is the original file extension.
   It might be necessary to make `%drive_letter%` match the current drive letter by either:

   - change the drive letter *(should work)*
   - or rename all files to match the current drive letter *(I assume this won't work because this probably breaks the compatibility with the `INFO2` file)*

Now the deleted files should show up in the recycle bin.
Is there any better solution? If so, please post as an answer.